# QT Can't read from a file

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to open a file from a specific location and it seems to find the path properly, but I can't figure out why it always skips the while loop.

```
QString utm_file_loc = "C:\\Example\\test\\UTM_Zone.config";
QFile fileutm(utm_file_loc);
QTextStream utm_in(&fileutm);
QString value;
while(!utm_in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = utm_in.readLine();               
    line.replace(" ", "");
    if( (line.indexOf("#") <0 || 1 < line.indexOf("#")) &&
        (line.contains("UTM_ZONE=")) )
    {
        value = line.mid(line.indexOf("=")+1);
        break;
    }
}
```

The config file is 1 line and contains UTM_ZONE = 17

I thought it might have to do with it being 1 line and so it always thinks it's at the end, but I tried adding more lines before and after to the file and it still skips the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the line where you make the File object and the line where you pass it into the QTextStream, you need to open the file:

```
if ( fileutm.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) )
{
    //Create you QTextStream and use it here...
}
else
{
    //Report error opening file here....
}
```

Comment: Wow yeah, I just noticed that and was just about to answer the question myself. Thanks!